# Как в VisualStudio 2017 включить поддержку JSX файлов?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc, jsx

У меня есть проект `VisualStudio 2017` построенный на `ASP.NET Core 2.0 React Template`. Он по умолчанию включает работу с `TSX` файлами `TypeScript`.
Я хочу писать в своём проекте на обычном `React JavaScript (JSX)` но при попытке скомпилировать и запустить проект с таким файлом в браузер выдаёт ошибку

> ... LoginPanel.jsx Unexpected token (16:15)
>
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Как можно включить поддержку стандартных `JSX` файлов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогло вот это:

В файле `webpack.config.js` изменить эту строчку добавив паттерн для jsx, как сделано в примере

```
 rules: [
           { test: /\.(tsx|jsx)?$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: 'awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true' },
```

В файле `tsconfig.json` добавить

```
"allowJs":  true
```